# Correttezza grammaticale di queste frasi?

Tags: grammar

1)molte/poche/alcune cose che trovi qui non si trovano da nessuna parte

2)poca/molta acqua che c'è qui è davvero buona

Queste frasi, così strutturate sono corrette oppure bisogna aggiungere "di"?

Ad esempio "un pò/poca/molta DELL'ACQUA che c'è qui è davvero buona"

Ovviamente per poca/molta intendo una piccola/grande parte/quantità

Comment: Forse sarebbe meglio scrivere le frasi che ti interessano separatamente, senza le barre diagonali, perché non sempre le varie possibilità sono intercambiabili. Nota per esempio che “alcune cose che trovi qui non si trovano da nessuna parte” e “poche cose che trovi qui non si trovano da nessuna parte” hanno significati quasi opposti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le frasi sono corrette. *Molto* e *poco* sono aggettivi che possono essere usati al maschile/femminile, singolare/plurale e non hanno la preposizione *di*. L’altra espressione di quantità è *un po’ di*. (*Un po’* si scrive con l’apostrofo e non con l’accento).

Comment: Giusto; d'altro canto è corretto anche “molta dell'acqua che c'è qui” etc. E anche “Molte/Alcune/Poche delle cose che trovi qui...” è corretto.

Comment: @DaG concordo con il tuo suggerimento di separare le frasi.

Comment: Quindi l'uso della preposizione 'di" è facoltativo con molto/poco?  Per esempio: 1) tanta carne che c'è qui è buona 2) Tanta della carne che c'è qui è buona... non c'è alcuna differenza?

Comment: Non lo so... mi suona di più dire " mi piace molta dell'acqua che bevi" piuttosto che " mi piace molta acqua che bevi" ... le frasi magari saranno un pò stupidotte ma comunque...

Comment: @Nakamura, perché fai una domanda con “molto/poco” e poi un esempio con “tanto”? Chiarisciti le idee su che cosa vuoi chiedere e poi chiedilo. (E ricorda che “po'” si scrive con l'apostrofo, non con l'accento.)

Comment: Si,  è vero.  Ma fondamentalmente tra "tanto" e "molto" c'è poca differenza. Io mi chiedevo se ci fosse differenza tra i quattro esempi da me fatti (nei commenti), se l'introduzione della preposizione "di" cambiasse qualcosa... insomma, cosa cambia? Mi scuso se sono stato frainteso mi scuso